# Sonarqube - get users from LDAP

Tags: ldap, sonarqube

we have an issue of finding LDAP users that never logged in to the Sonarqube before. Is it possible? Sounds like a simlpe thing to assign an issue or add some user to the group without forcing this user to login to the Sonarqube before that. I'm I wrong?

Versions:

- sonar-ldap-plugin-2.2.0.608
- SonarQube: Version 6.7.2 (build 37468)

Our LDAP configuration is:

```
# LDAP configuration
# General Configuration
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
ldap.authentication=simple
ldap.url=ldap://ldap.com

ldap.bindDn=CN=user,DC=our,DC=company,DC=com
ldap.bindPassword=PASS
sonar.forceAuthentication=true

# User Configuration
ldap.user.baseDn=DC=our,DC=company,DC=com
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={login}))
ldap.user.realNameAttribute=cn
ldap.user.emailAttribute=mail
```

Comment: I don't think so. The documentation on their LDAP plugin says `During the first authentication trial, if the password is correct, the SonarQube database is automatically populated with the new user. Each time a user logs into SonarQube, the username, the email and the groups this user belongs to that are refreshed in the SonarQube database.`